# Python & C++ dll debugging

Tags: python, c++, dll, callback, ctypes

I am implementing a Python module to interact with a C++ dll using ctypes. 
The dll has a SetCallback function with this signature:

```
typedef bool (*tcallback)(BYTE* pData);
bool SetCallback(tcallback pCallback);
```

where pCallback is a pointer to the callback function:

```
bool Callback(BYTE* data);
```

**My Python code:**

```
def py_callback(self, response):
    print('Callback output:')
    print(response.decode('utf-8'))
    return ctypes.c_bool(True)

def set_callback(self): 
    type_callback = ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(ctypes.c_bool, ctypes.c_char_p)
    c_callback = type_callback(self.py_callback)
    return self.conn.SetCallback(ctypes.byref(c_callback))
```

Calling callback function by the dll crashes Python without any traceback. pdb is of not much help either, this is all I see:

```
> <string>(1)<module>()->None
(Pdb)
> c:\python\lib\bdb.py(435)run()
-> self.quitting = True
```

I've spent really much time trying to figure it out, I hope you can help me out!

**Update: solved**

Many thanks to @Fireho and @eryksun in the comments,
the problem was:

1. ctypes.byref() incorrectly passed tcallback* instead of tcallback to SetCallback();
2. c_callback was not retained in the code and got garbage-collected after set_callback() returned

**Working code:**

```
def py_callback(self, response):
    print('Callback output:')
    print(response.decode('utf-8'))
    return ctypes.c_bool(True)

def set_callback(self): 
    type_callback = ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(ctypes.c_bool, ctypes.c_char_p)
    self.c_callback = type_callback(self.py_callback)
    return self.conn.SetCallback(self.c_callback)
```

Comment: Have you tried getting rid of `ctypes.byref`? I don't know much about Python interaction with C++ DLLs, but perhaps you are passing `tcallback*` instead of `tcallback` - that easily explains the crash.

Comment: @Fireho, using `byref` is the first problem, which does incorrectly pass a `tcallback *`. The next problem after that is the code isn't keeping a reference to `c_callback`, so it will be automatically deallocated when `set_callback` returns, which leaves the library holding an invalid pointer.

Comment: @Fireho, I tried indeed, but it did not help - apparently, owing to the problem with a vanishing reference to c_callback.

Comment: @eryksun, this helped, thanks a lot for the input!